# How is Wireguard managed?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, wireguard

I use Wireguard as my primary VPN (running a server and having several clients connecting to it) - it works fine but I realized today that I do not understand how it is actually managed. It is the following sequence of events which led me to that realization:

- client A and client B are defined in `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`. They both connect correctly.
- I added some packages that modified the kernel. This triggered the usual messages about `modprobe` etc. I never really paid attention to those as they were acknowledgements that everything was OK.
- when the step above is done, client A is still connected, client B does not connect anymore. I am trying with a client C and it connects.

I then had a look at `wg show` and it was **not** showing peer B. Since peer B (= client B) is in `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` then something must have gone wrong. Solution: reboot.

After the reboot client A reconnects automatically, client B still does not connect (and is still not visible in `wg show`, even in the disconnected state).

How could have it be connected in the first place at all? (I ask myself).

Last idea:

```
wg-quick down wg0
wg-quick up wg0
```

and everything is back to normal, client A and client B connect.

This means one thing: the initial (post-boot or post-apt-which-changed-kernel) startup of `wireguard` must use another configuration file. This is conceivable - client A was set up a long time ago and client B added only recently (to `/etc/wireguard/wg0`) so it may be that I forgot where I set this up.

I had the problem above once in the past, now that I remember it, and fixed it with the two `wg-quick` commands but had no time to debate any further (which would explain how client B managed to connect at all)

**My question: in Ubuntu 18.04, what is the service actually starting `wireguard` (installed from the `wireguard` PPA) and where is the configuration file used by that service?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding another answer because I ended up using another approach. That one is based on the `wg-quick@.service` template.

I enable (and start, stop, etc.) it via `systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0.service` and the configuration lives in `/etc/wireguard`. It has the classical format of Wireguard.

In order to manage the configuration, I use the excellent [Wg Gen Web](https://github.com/vx3r/wg-gen-web) interface.

Answer (score 2):

Wireguard is started via `systemd-networkd`. The installation also creates a new interface `wg0`.

The configuration is done via two files (`somename` can be anything, for instance `wg0` or `wireguard`)<sup>(1)</sup>

1. `/etc/systemd/network/somename.netdev`

This file will hold the configuration of the [interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#%5BWireGuard%5D%20Section%20Options) and [peers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#%5BWireGuardPeer%5D%20Section%20Options). It uses `[WireGuard]` and `[WireGuardPeer]` instead of the usual `[Interface]` and `[Peer]` (see <sup>(1)</sup>)

```
[NetDev]
Name = wg0
Kind = wireguard
Description = Wireguard

[WireGuard]
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <your private key>

# laptop
[WireGuardPeer]
PublicKey = h/trC+5Z8qbGBJtroYITQGMNUn5XQZ/JRqVR3iIH5Ro=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.20.2/32
```

2. `/etc/systemd/network/somename.network`

This file will hold the IP-related configuration of the interface (nothing specifically wireguard-related here)

```
[Match]
Name = wg0

[Network]
Address = 192.168.20.1/32

[Route]
Gateway = 192.168.20.1
Destination = 192.168.20.0/24
```

These configuration files are read upon a `systemctl [re]start systemd-networkd`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that the configuration file referred to in various documentations (`/etc/wireguard/wg0`) is not used with `systemd-networkd`. It would be used if you ran `wg-quick` commands.

*This answer is here thanks to [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) and him pointing to `systemd-networkd` and its configuration files*